# How to properly define completeness of a set

Tags: real-analysis, logic, real-numbers, axioms

A few weeks back I picked up a 1960 copy of *General Theory of Functions and Integration* by Taylor at a half price bookstore.

I started reading this and got up to the definition of completeness of an ordered field which they defined as follows (paraphrasing)

> Divide your ordered field into an upper and lower partition $(L,R)$ via some inequality. An ordered field is complete iff for all possible partitions, either $L$ has a maximum or $R$ has a minimum

Now I was used to the definition

> An ordered field is complete iff every bounded subset $S$ has a least upper bound and greatest lower bound.

Going off memory I might have phrased that wrong, but I know these two statements are equivalent. However my question is **when proving completeness for the first time, what is the correct definition to use?**

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as "correct" definition. But people have preferences, and many arguments can be made about the pedagogical advantages of starting with one over the other. To further complicate, the second definition listed here I recall learning it as the Least Upper Bound property and by completeness, we meant every Cauchy sequence of a metric space converged within the space. We assumed LUB property of $\mathbb{R}$, and proved completeness but I am particularly fond of the, somewhat lengthy, Cauchy sequence construction of $\mathbb{R}$, in which one has to prove the LUB.

Comment: Don't forget that your definitions of completeness refer to an _ordered_ field. If they refer to a field, they do not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course your second definition is more useful in our daily work and gives quick results in situations coming up hundreds of times. But it involves "all subsets of ${\mathbb R}$", and this is indeed a large community of objects. For an *axiom* one would like simpler setups. That's what your first definition does; it just talks about splittings of ${\mathbb R}$ into a lower and an upper part: Any such splitting hits a unique number (which then can belong to the lower or the upper part).

Answer (score 3):

I was used to the following definition:

> An ordered field $R$ is *complete<sup>2</sup>* if every subset of $R$ that is bounded above has a least upper bound (in $R$).

This definition of completeness is (apparently) different from the one you were used:

> An ordered field $R$ is *complete<sup>1</sup>* if every bounded subset of $R$ that has a least upper bound and a greatest lower bound (in $R$).

Now it is quite easy to prove that an ordered field is complete<sup>2</sup> if and only if it is complete<sup>1</sup> (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/41597/288417), for instance). So, what is *the* definition of completeness? Both are equivalent, and there is no logical reason to prefer one or the other, since both of them denote the same object (the set of real numbers). In other words, the two definitions of completeness are *extensionally* identical.

Of course, the two definition of completeness are *intensionally* different, in the sens that they describe the same object in two (slightly) different ways, but none of them is "more correct" than the other, because both of them talk about the same object. Is there any difference if I define Rome as "the current capital of Italy" or as "the city of the Colosseum"?

Intensional differences can be relevant from a *pedagogical* point of view, because a way to describe an object might involve more technical notions with respect to another approach; or from a *pragmatical* point of view, because one of the ways to present the object might be more convenient (in the sense that it asks for less logical steps) to prove certain properties; but they are irrelevant from a *logical* point of view.

The difference between the definitions of complete<sup>2</sup> and complete<sup>1</sup> might seem ridiculous, but what I said is still valid if you use other definitions of completeness, such as the convergence of every Cauchy sequence, or the one you mentioned about partitions.

Comment: They can become relevant from a logical point of view when you consider different foundations. For example, the Dedekind definition of reals and the definition in terms of Cauchy sequences separate in constructive logic. I'm not even sure that the two definitions of completeness you gave are equivalent constructively (though it'd likely be necessary to be more precise about what some of the terms mean to be sure).

Comment: @DerekElkins - Good point! I guess this is out of the scope of the question of the OP, but it is important to point it out (and be aware of it).